# Reference about Fourier versus Laplace transform

Tags: reference-request, laplace-transform, fourier-transform

I often come up searching on internet about the relation between Fourier and (double sided) Laplace transform, but without getting places where these are treated extensively together. In particular I would like to have a reference which clarifies the convergence of the integrals, the analytic continuations, the inverse transforms and that compares explicitly these aspects for the two transforms, which are obviously intimately related. Is there such a book that you would suggest ?